# Haml page not passing 508 compliance due to empty links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, section508

In my haml page, I have a anchor tag that is only for enclosing an icon. The functionality works fine, but when I perform the 508 compliance it complains about the href being a `#`. Below is the two lines in the HAML file:

```
=link_to '#', aria_label: "Change Icon", class: 'btn btn-info', id: 'icon-button' do           
  %i{class: icon, id: 'icon-button', data: {icon: icon}}
```

I have tried switching the `<a>` with a button but that creates another 508 compliance issue of no value for a button.

Comment: inside link_to `href` use `javascript:void(0)` instead of using a `#`

Comment: I tried still get the same error reported (below is the error text): Remove the empty link or provide text within the link that describes the functionality and/or target of that link.
The Algorithm... in English
An anchor element has an href attribute, but contains no text (or only spaces) and no images with alternative text.

Comment: seems like your haml code contains some error. Could you check this with a erb?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FontAwesome accessibility documentation](http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/), you should add `aria-hidden="true"` to the `i` tag.

```
= link_to '#', aria_label: "Change Icon", class: 'btn btn-info', id: 'icon-button' do
    %i{class: icon, id: 'icon-button', data: {icon: icon}, aria_hidden: true}
```

Alternatively, you can add a span that will be read by screen reader only, if you are using Bootstrap.

```
= link_to '#', aria_label: "Change Icon", class: 'btn btn-info', id: 'icon-button' do
    %i{class: icon, id: 'icon-button', data: {icon: icon}}
    %span.sr-only
      Change Icon
```